# How to control a specific USB port in windows with python?

Tags: python

I'm need to control a certain USB port in windows. I am working on a projet to automate Testcases.

*Problem*: In some tests you need to plug-in and out the USB pendrive to run the test 200 times for example.

*Solution*: Write a python program and integrate it in the tests to emulate this process of plug-in and out of a USB.

i have found this code below but "subprocess" doesn't have run reference

```
import subprocess
# Fetches the list of all usb devices:
result = subprocess.run(['devcon', 'hwids', '=usb'], 
    capture_output=True, text=True)

# ... add code to parse the result and get the hwid of the device you want ...

subprocess.run(['devcon', 'disable', parsed_hwid]) # to disable
subprocess.run(['devcon', 'enable', parsed_hwid]) # to enable
```

Write a python program and integrate it in the tests to emulate this process of plug-in and out of a USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is the solution i was able to use and it is working fine with me.

```
import subprocess

# find all devices command
Find_command = 'C:/Windows/SysWOW64/devcon.exe find *'

#list HW ids of devices
hwIds_command = 'C:/devcon.exe hwids *'

#Enable
Enable_command = 'C:/devcon.exe enable *PID_1016'

#Disable
Disable_command = 'C:/devcon.exe disable *mouse*'

#Find Device
Find_SpecificDevice_command = 'C:/devcon.exe find *PID_1016 '
find= True
try:
    if find:
        result = subprocess.check_output(Find_SpecificDevice_command,shell=True ,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        print(result)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

**If you have any questions regarding the solution feel free to ask.**

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.run` is the replacement for `subprocess.call` that has different arguments so they had to give it a new name. But as in this case the code requires none of the new features you can just replace `subprocess.run` with `subprocess.call`.

And in the case of `subprocess.run` with the option `capture_output` that can be replaced with `subprocess.check_output`.

Comment: I should have said that both options should have been omitted.